# Как вернуть все значения i в цикле for

Tags: python, массивы, функции, циклы, for

Это задача с Codewars

Мне нужно вернуть массив n кратных x

```
     count_by(2,5) должен возвращать [2,4,6,8,10]
     count_by(1,10) #should return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Мне нужно вернуть все значения i в данном цикле, я не понимаю механизм for, если я пишу return внутри цикла он возвращает первый элемент i, если я пишу return уже после цикла for он возвращает только последний i. Как мне правильно написать цикл чтобы вернуть все элементы

```
         def count_by(x, n):
             for i in range(1,n):
                 i = i * x
             return (i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно создать список, добавлять в него элементы, и вернуть список. Обратите также внимание на верхнюю границу range

```
def count_by(x, n):
   res = []
   for i in range(1,n+1):
       res.append(i * x)
   return res
```

Более питонически - использовать генератор списков:

```
def count_by(x, n):
   return [i*x for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!! А если без списка, можно ли просто вернуть все значения из цикла.

Comment: Вам указано в задании `вернуть массив n кратных x` - в Python это список.  Вообще без создания списка можно использовать yield, но это сложнее использовать и, мне кажется, вам пока рановато.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй это, может не очень красиво но ты же в кодварс а не на собеседовании)

```
def count_by(x, n):
    returns=[]
    for i in range(x, n*x+x, x):
        returns.append(i)
    return returns
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```py
def count_by(x, n):
    return [*range(x, x*n+1, x)]
```

или немножко подлиннее и помедленнее, но и так можно:

```py
def count_by(x, n):
    return [*map(x.__mul__, range(1, n+1))]
```